# Don't show code on special pages and action=edit pages

Tags: php, mediawiki

I have a MediaWiki site. I am adding Facebook comments code to my skin. However, I don't want it to show on special pages and edit pages. 
How do I code this in php?
Thanks

I found a way to see if it is a special page

```
$string =  urlencode($wgTitle->getLocalURL()); 
echo $string;
if (stristr($string, 'Special') == TRUE){}
```

for edit pages can I use $wgActionPaths? but I can't figure out how to use this variable.

Comment: What hook are you using to display the comments? Or are you adding code directly to the skin?

Comment: I'm adding code directly to the skin. I just can't figure out how to test if it is an edit page or not. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( $wgTitle->isSpecialPage() ) { ....
```

To check against other namespaces use Title's `getNamespace()` function in conjunction with one of NS_* constants from includes/Defines.php. Also, try not to use $wgTitle as it will be deprecated soon - instead, use [request context](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aRequestContext) if possible.

Comment: Thanks the code works perfectly. Any ideas how I could code to check if action=edit?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used the code ($wgTitle->getNamespace() == NS_USER || $wgTitle->getNamespace() == NS_IMAGE || $wgTitle->getNamespace() == NS_EDIT_NEW) to check the page type. I haven't worked it out using the request context. If you can help me with that I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: $wgTitle->getNamespace() == NS_EDIT_NEW didn't work, for edit page I used if($_GET["action"] == edit)